# Health Service Bot test not working in Microsoft Teams

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams

I have a Health Service bot working fine in the emulator, but when I go to Integrations/Channels/MS Teams/ and test it opens the bot and goes to a blank screen, the "help" command works only, I don't see any way to start the scenario automatically.

I already tried Configuration/Conversation and put the "Automatic welcome scenario" as the scenario but it still doesn't work.

It also won't display a "welcome text" set there when I tested that out.

Not sure, is there some limitation in testing in MS Teams?

Comment: I assume you're implementing the conversationUpdate event? If so, please post your code so we can see more clearly what the issue is

Comment: @Stven Could you please share more details as asked by @Hilton? Also Could you please go through this samples [welcome user](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/03.welcome-user) and [Proactive sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages)?